# Excel/VBA/SQL - refresh not working

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I've created a VBA script that updates the CommandText of an SQL connection in order to pass a parameter from Excel to a stored procedure - this works fine except that the query doesn't update itself..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim BillDate As Date
Dim BillDateFormat As String
BillDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value

BillDateFormat = Format(BillDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("BillDateConnection").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "EXEC TTKWBillingTest @BillDate = '" & BillDateFormat & "'"


End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("BillDateConnection").Refresh

End Sub
```

I'm finding that the data only refreshes on the first refresh and subsequent refreshes update the CommandText but the data on the worksheet does not refresh.

I've tried adding..

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

but this doesn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...I figured this out.

'Enable background refresh' needs to be deselected in the connection properties.

The table refreshes every time without this option.

Answer (score 1):

Put code in ThieWorkbook object so that it fires when Excel opens

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()

For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
   'Get current background-refresh value
   bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
   'Temporarily disable background-refresh
   objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
   objConnection.Refresh         'Refresh this connection
   'Set background-refresh value back to original value
   objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
Next

End sub
```

NB This can cause problems if the data connection is set to update on open! Best to remove this option from the connection manager!

To update via a button:

```
Private Sub Cmd_RefreshData_Click()
    Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open"
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Lbl_LastRefresh_Click
End Sub
```

Lbl_LastRefresh uses Now() to display the last refresh time

Comment: This needs to be updated from a CommandButton as it will be used several times while the workbook is open.

Comment: Outstanding!  You saved me!